# update the nested array in mongodb using node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I need to update a particular element of the nested array in mongoDB

My mongoDB data looks like below. I need to match the value accessid and name to update the status. The input content has

```
{"accessid" : 1627047023995, "name" : Name 09, "status" : 100 }
```

The input content may belong to any `level`

```
  {
        "_id" : ObjectId("60fac46ffcbf5287248460a9"), 
        "levelone" : [ 
            {
                "level" : [ 
                    {
                        "name" : "Name 01",
                        "status" : 5
                    }, 
                    {
                        "name" : "Name 02",
                        "status" : 0
                    }, 
                    {
                        "name" : "Name 03",
                        "status" : 0
                    } 
                ], 
                "accessid" : "1627047023995" 
            }, 
            {
                "level" : [ 
                    {
                        "name" : "Name 09",
                        "status" : 5
                    }, 
                    {
                        "name" : "Name 15",
                        "status" : 3
                    } 
                ], 
                "accessid" : "1627047023995" 
            }
        ],
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-07-23T13:30:23.995Z") 
    }
```

I have tried to update the status, but it is updating only the first index value - name: Name 01 status. Please guide to resolve the issue.

```
collections.updateOne({
  'levelone.level.accessid': accessid,
  'levelone.level.name': name
}, { '$set': { 'levelone.$.level.status': status } }).exec();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [arrayFilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) positional update,

- query with `$elemMatch` to filter the main document
- arrayFilters to define `a` variable for `accessid` and `b` for `name`

```
await collections.updateOne({
  levelone: {
    $elemMatch: {
      accessid: accessid,
      "level.name": name
    }
  }
},
{
  $set: {
    "levelone.$[a].level.$[b].status": status
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    { "a.accessid": accessid },
    { "b.name": name }
  ]
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/aQ7vcre8Q-c)